# How to resume downloading of Apple Hosted Content?

Tags: ios, download, in-app-purchase

I'm using Apple Hosted Content for my In-App Purchase. There is no problem to purchase and download now. However I have no idea about how to resume downloading if I quit app and return to my application again. There is no document about this part at all. Does anybody have experiences of this? Thanks

Comment: I believe that content keeps downloading in the background.

Comment: Download in background？How do you know that?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think Apple said so at WWDC 3

Comment: I saw this somewhere too. But it seems not like this. I tried so many times already. Unless I did something wrong or because I ran the app in sandbox environment.

Comment: Any suggestion? I can't find any document and information in Apple's developer's forum.